# I am having trouble with numpy's lstsq when I have complex data and multiple right hand sides

Tags: numpy, least-squares

I have noticed a problem with numpy's lstsq when I have a complex matrix and multiple right hand sides. If the number of right hand sides is large enough - then I end up with a malloc core dump. This is strange since lstsq should compute the SVD and then just multiply it across all of the right hand sides (and my work around is to use SVD in exactly this way). This seems to happen on linux and windows - and also Python 2.7 and 3.5. I am attaching a code segment. I would appreciate to know if anyone thinks that I have made a mistake in my usage of lstsq or a namespace conflict.

```
# test python complex lstsq against multiple right hand sides
# The lstsq code works great on real valued problems 
# - but freaks out on complex - and can cause a malloc core dump
from scipy import *
from pylab import *

Ntest = 700
G = randn(200,50)+1j*randn(200,50)
u = randn(50,Ntest) + 1j*randn(50,Ntest)
b = dot(G,u)

# this works for moderately large Ntest (linus and windows, python 2.7 and 3.5)
U,S,VH = svd(G,full_matrices=False)
K = dot(VH.conjugate().transpose(),dot(diag(1.0/S),U.conjugate().transpose()))
u2 = dot(K,b)

print('found u2 shape',u2.shape)
print('SVD solution is good - error {0:g}'.format(abs(u2-u).max()))

print('\n')

# whereas, this crashes for some Ntest big enough for your system
u3,res,rnk,sv = lstsq(G,b)
print('found u3 shape',u3.shape)
print('LSTSQ solution is good - error {0:g}'.format(abs(u3-u).max()))
```

Comment: Code (exactly copied) works for me (numpy 1.13.1).

Comment: My version is 1.11.3, It does seem to work for scipy.linalg.lstsq (version 0.18.1) which is a slighly different implementation than the numpy one.

Comment: seems there is a difference between u3,res,rnk,sv = np.linalg.lstsq(G,b) and 
u3,res,rnk,sv = scipy.linalg.lstsq(G,b)

Comment: I will look into updating

Comment: still crashes for me on 1.13.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, (using anaconda)

Comment: still happens on Windows 10 with anaconda and np.__version__ = 1.13.1 (python 3.5.4 and ipython 6.1.0)

Comment: That's interesting (although i'm using an anaconda MKL build too)!

Comment: Had a typo - tried the openblas but forgot to uncomment scipy.linalg.lstsq (which worked) when I ran numpy.linalg.lstsq it still crashed

Comment: This problem was verified on the numpy github site and a solution has been posted for the next release